# Different Definitions on the Differentiability of Functions on a closed set.

Tags: functions, derivatives, definition

I have encountered three different definitions on the differentiablity of functions on a closed set.

In the following, suppose that $\Omega\subset M$ is a (open) domain, where $M$ is a manifold. The three definitions are

1. We say $f: \bar\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ belongs to $C^k(\bar\Omega)$, if there is a function $\tilde f\in C^k(\tilde\Omega)$ defined on a domain $\tilde \Omega \supset \Omega$ such that $f = \tilde f|_\Omega$.
2. The function $f: \bar\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ belongs to $C^k(\bar\Omega)$ if for each point $x\in \bar\Omega$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a $C^k$ function $\tilde f$ defined on $U$ such that $f|_U = \tilde f|_U$.
3. Suppose that $\partial \Omega$ is the boundary of $\Omega$ and it is of $C^k$, that is for each point $x\in\partial\Omega$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a $C^k$ diffeomorphism $\Phi: U \to V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, where $V$ is a neighborhood of $0\in \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\Phi(U\cap\Omega) = V\cap \{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}|x^n >0\}$. Since for the part of the boundary $V\cap \{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}|x^n =0\}$, the differentiablity is easy to defined using the directional derivative. Then we say $f\in C^k(\bar\Omega)$ is for each $x\in\omega$, $f\circ\Phi^{-1}$ is of $C^k$.

What's the relationship among the three definitions?

Comment: Any news on this question? Is there a chance you remember the references this definitions originated from (German references are fine with me)?

Answer (score 2):

I think all of  these are equivalent. Clearly (1) implies (2) because you can always choose $U = \tilde \Omega$. To show the converse, pick for every  $x \in \overline\Omega$ a neighborhood $U_x$ as in (2) and an extension $\tilde f_x \in C^k(U)$ of $f\vert_{\overline\Omega \cap U}$. Now set $\tilde\Omega = \bigcup_{x \in X} U_x$, pick a partition of unity $\{\phi_x\}_{x \in X}$ on $\tilde\Omega$ subordinate to the cover $\{U_x\}_{x \in X}$ and set $\tilde f = \sum_{x \in X} \phi_x \tilde f_x$. This function has the required properties.

In the case where $\partial \Omega$ is $C^k$ we also have the equivalence of (1) and (3). For this we need to show that the usual definition of a $C^k$ function on open subsets $U$ of the half-space $\mathbb{H}^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x^n = 0\}$ agrees with definition (1). The implication (1) $\implies$ (2) is immediate. For the converse we can use a version of [Borel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma)$^1$. This guarantees the existence of a $C^k$ function $F: U \cap (\mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times \{0\}) \times (-1, 0]$ s.t. ${\partial_n}^kF(x, 0) = {\partial_n}^kf(x, 0)$ for all $x \in U \cap (\mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times \{0\})$. Hence the function
$$
\tilde f(x, t) = \begin{cases}
f(x, t) & t \geq 0 \\
F(x, t) & t \leq 0
\end{cases}
$$
defined on $U \cup \left(\left(U \cap \mathbb{R}^{n-1}\right) \times (-1, 0] \right)$ satisfies the required properties.

$^1$The version proven in Wikipedia is not quite strong enough for this purpose. The version that we need is Corollary 1.3.4 in Hörmander's book *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I*. The crucial difference is that Hörmanders version only requires $C^{k-j}$-regularity for the prescribed $j$-th derivative in $t$-direction.